# "Unable to fo find git in your PATH"

Tags: flutter

Recently I wanted to start the mobile developpement with flutter, I am watching videos to help me install all the settings for that but when I try "flutter doctor" it is saying "unable to find git in your PATH" the problem is that I had already installed git and I changed the path to it, i tested everything i do not know whats to do now.

I installed git when it said "Unable to fo find git in your PATH" but nothing had changed, I also tried to change the Path but same thing, nothing changed. I tested "ping" in the cmd but it printed an error so I thought maybe the problem came from other thing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Git using the below command line:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

You can also add to your PATH variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32
```

> If you are windows, 10 users.You nedd to run CMD as Administrator. It
> will solved your problem.

> You can also try by uninstalling and reinstall GIT to solve my problem.

Comment: It solved the problem with `ping` but the command `sudo apt -get install git` print an error message about sudo that it was not recognised as a command

Comment: I think the problem are thoses variables I changed everything maybe it is that..

Comment: Awesome! how did you use `ping`?

Answer (score 0):

After trying more than three hours I find the solution of this problems.

1:The most simple and easy method is that, download your flutter sdk and git in the same directory.

[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsazJ.png][1]
2:Then copy the bin path of both in add to your environment variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).