# Flutter Unable to find git in your PATH (Windows)

Tags: flutter, git, environment-variables, path-variables, flutter-doctor

I created a new user on my windows PC and can't get flutter to work on it.
Flutter and git are both installed in a shared folder (like `C:\shared_programs\...`).
I made sure that both users have full access in the security properties of that folder.

I added all these to the System Path Variable:

- `C:\shared_programs\flutter\bin`
- `C:\Windows\System32`
- `C:\shared_programs\Git\cmd`

When I run `where git` or `where flutter`, the correct paths are printed.

But when I run `flutter`, it returns `"Error: Unable to find git in your PATH."`
Why? How do I fix this?

(I think this question is not a duplicate because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678581) question was fixed by adding something to the path which I already did, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132199) question is about the `where` command not working, which isn't my problem. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223809) one also doesn't work for me.)

Comment: Is this only a problem for the new user? Or is it a problem for all the existing users too?

Comment: I installed fvm with cmd, but IntelliJ was using powershell. Running `git rev-parse HEAD` in the flutter location through powershell failed ('folder' is owned by xyz but the current user is abc). By calling the following command in powershell this fixed it for me `git config --global --add safe.directory C:/path_to_fvm_home/versions/3.7.0`

Comment: @merlin2011 only for the new user

Comment: @jdepypere thank you! That fixed it for me. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it (it didn't have anything to do with powershell/cmd for me tho, IntelliJ used cmd for me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and your post incited me to investigate it further.

Fvm had installed flutter 3.7.0 through cmd. Using cmd I could also successfully run `git rev-parse HEAD` in the flutter sdk folder.

It seems however that executing the same command through powershell didn't work (and IntelliJ uses powershell for me).

By calling the following command in powershell this fixed it for me: `git config --global --add safe.directory C:/path_to_fvm_home/versions/3.7.0`

Comment: I installed flutter through cmd and running `git rev-parse HEAD` in cmd in the flutter directory returned `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at ...`, and running `git config --global --add safe.directory C:\path\to\flutter` fixed it. A little different from your issue, but thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

If none of the other solutions work, this might help someone.

```
git config --global --unset core.safecrlf
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**